# Realm insert or update object with primary key

Tags: android, realm

Im not sure i understand the different between them:
As I see it, `realm.createObject` can't really update existing key (got the error: Primary key value already exists)

**OPTION 1:**

```
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                CacheFastObjTest a = realm.createObject(CacheFastObjTest.class, key);
                a.setDataType(className.getName());
                a.setExpireTimestamp(expires.getTime());
                a.setText1("dsaf");
                a.setText2("234234324");
                realm.insertOrUpdate(a);
            }
        });
    }
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                CacheFastObjTest a = new CacheFastObjTest();
                a.setKey(key);
                a.setDataType(className.getName());
                a.setExpireTimestamp(expires.getTime());
                a.setText1("dsaf");
                a.setText2("234234324");
                realm.insertOrUpdate(a);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer:

In the end, the result is the same.

**Option 1** is better practice because when you use:

```
realm.createObject(CacheFastObjTest.class, key);
```

Realm is wrap your object and make sure you use the correct primary key otherwise the developer will get exceptions about it.

In the other hand, developers can use **options 2**

```
CacheFastObjTest a = new CacheFastObjTest();
a.setKey(key);
```

for the scenarios above:

> Note that Realm.createObject returns a new object with all fields set
>   to their default values. If the object is a class with a primary key,
>   this could create a conflict—there might be an object with that
>   primary key set already. To avoid this, you can create an unmanaged
>   object, set its field values, then add it to the Realm with
>   copyToRealm or insert: Copy to clipboard.

[More information about realm with Primary key](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primary-keys)

Answer (score 2):

```
CacheFastObjTest a = realm.where(CacheFastObjTest.class).equalTo("id", key).findFirst();
if(a == null) {
     a = realm.createObject(CacheFastObjTest.class, key);
}
a.setDataType(className.getName());
a.setExpireTimestamp(expires.getTime());
a.setText1("dsaf");
a.setText2("234234324");
//realm.insertOrUpdate(a);
```

Comment: But then is so much not efficiency no?!

Comment: Eh, it's fast..  Generally I prefer this approach if I have `RealmList`/`RealmObject` fields.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using realm, you need to programmatically increment your object id before save it. On the below code you check if there's any value stored on your table. If there's no value there, you just set the id of the object to 1 as a default value to the nextId.

```
int nextId = 1;
if (realm.where(yourclass).max("id") != null){
    nextId = realm.where(yourclass).max("id").intValue() + 1;
}
yourclass.setId(nextId);
```

Comment: Yeah. but whats the different between the realm.createObject and the manually create my object and update them

Comment: According to Realm documentation ([link](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)), copyToRealm will persist unmanaged objects and createObject will create managed objects directly

Comment: But im not talking about copyToRealm. Just new CacheFastObjTest() with my constructor.